# No more loops in R

Tags: r, loops

I have come to the conclusion that R experts are not very much fond of loops; however, this truth is a bit harsh on me as an ex java programmer.

I want to dynamically create 5 variables: `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `x4` and `x5` and assign each one of them a random value.

```
> i = 1
> 
> while(i <= 5)
 {
   assign(paste("x", i, sep = ""), rnorm(1))
   i = i + 1       
 }
> x1
[1] 0.3853609
> x2
[1] 1.626055
> x3
[1] -1.043699
> x4
[1] 0.3449921
> x5
[1] -0.9768416
```

Well, this uses a `while` loop and I am looking for the R way of doing this. I tried:

```
assign(paste("x", 1:5, sep=""), rnorm(1)
```

which gives an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I do not think that `assign` is vectorised, so you *have* to use a loop with `assign`. But don't use `assign` here. It's not necessary.

Comment: Your problem is that you think you need 5 variables. You need only one containing 5 values. And we are fond of loops and use them all the time. Hoewever, only if we need them.

Comment: Your final `assign` line doesn't give an error, it sits there waiting for a closing parenthesis.

Comment: You might want to read the [**about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [**FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) sections of the website to help you get the most out of Stack Overflow. If one of the below answers does solve your problem you may want to *consider* upvoting and/or marking it as accepted to show the question has been answered, by ticking the little green check mark next to the suitable answer. You are **not** obliged to do this, but it helps keep the site clean of unanswered questions and rewards those who take the time to solve your problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

R is vectorised. Just do..

```
x <- rnorm(5)
[1] -1.285847248  0.285534550  0.001136893  0.167311756 -1.420379168
```

Access each element using `[` (lists use the `[[` function to subset list elements). To get the 5th value...

```
x[5]
[1] -1.420379
```

This is basic R functionality. I suggest you do some reading of the tutorials on the [**R info**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) page of the tag wiki.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a more R-way to do it,

```
lval = as.list(rnorm(5))
names(lval) = paste0("x", seq_along(lval))

attach(lval) # if you really need those free variables in the workspace
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes not using loops is more loopy than using them.

`parse` will handle multiple expressions, so why not use that? Construct a vector of assignment calls, and use them:

```
> i=1:5
> s=paste("x",i,"<-rnorm(1)",sep="")
> eval(parse(text=s))
> ls()
[1] "i"  "s"  "x1" "x2" "x3" "x4" "x5"
> x1
[1] -0.6467902
> x2
[1] 1.376682
```

But this kind of thing has NO PLACE in real code, you might want to use it behind the scenes in generating variables for teaching examples but FOR PETE'S SAKE don't show this to the children!

Comment: Regarding the last sentence: I think you just did exactly that. ;)

Answer (score 2):

To avoid explicit loops when a function is not vectorized, you could an apply-type function, for example:

```
sapply(1:5, function(i){assign(paste("x", i, sep = ""), rnorm(1), pos = 1)})
```

or vectorize the function using `Vectorize`, for example:

```
assign.vect <- Vectorize(assign, vectorize.args = c("x","value"))
assign.vect(paste("x", 1:5, sep=""), rnorm(5), pos = 1)
```

Comment: +1 for your second use of Vectorize. I'm tempted to -1 for your initial use of `sapply`. The `apply` family are designed to be used for their return value, not a side effect. This is exactly what `for` is *designed* for - to be used for it's side effect, not it's return value (i.e. the value of the iterator after the last evaluation of the loop).

Comment: `*apply` functions are loops. I would even call them explicit loops.

Comment: @Roland, sure I meant 'explicit' in the sense of using explicitly writing `for` or `while`.

Comment: SimonO101, the purpose of the answer was to provide two ways to avoid 'explicit' loops in general, illustrated with the question's specific problem, which might not the most appropriate situation. One could argue that storing 5 variables is not the best choice, and prefer a vector (link you suggested in your answer) or a list.

Comment: `sapply` is an explicit loop and you are using it in the wrong way.

Comment: @SimonO101, could you please state what an 'explicit loop' is?

Comment: @QuantIbex `?lapply`... *lapply returns a list of the same length as X, each element of which is the result of applying FUN to the corresponding element of X*. What else if not a loop?

Comment: @SimonO101, you don't answer the question. I'm not questioning the fact that behind the scene there is a loop in `*apply` functions. I was requesting the definition of 'explicit loop', since apparently my interpretation is erroneous.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you are arguing over semantics. How do you read the above as anything other than a loop. In reality you should be more concerned with is your erroneous use of `sapply` (which by the way is twice as slow as using a `for` loop in this case - benchmark it). `*apply` is a loop construct, the first argument is the iterator.

Comment: `Vectorize` is just a wrapper for `lapply`.  You've shown two ways to hide the loop, which is a far cry from removing it.

Comment: one can use `plyr::l_ply` for quiet side-effects

Comment: @GSee, I don't claim that the proposed ways remove the loop, but avoids the explicit use of `for` or `while`. Is there a way to answer the OP's question without using *any* loop whatsoever (aside from writing 5 statements `x1<-rnorm(1)`, ..., `x5<-rnorm(1)`)?

Comment: @QuantIbex Yes, see baptiste's answer. Of course, there are still C loops involved, but these are much faster.